# functional programming - functional javascript - currying and partial implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, currying

I'm new to functional programming and I'm playing around with the ideas of currying and partial implementation in javascript to wrap my head around them. At the moment I'm trying to workout how I can pass a filter function.
Below is a line I saw in a tutorial

```
var seperate = arr => key => val => arr.filter(obj => obj[key] === val);
```

say I want to make the filter function a curried parameter so I can create partial implementations with different `filter` functions applied, such as a `var isHuman` or `var isLessThan50` etc.
Maybe I might want to pass as one argument for the partial implementation the dataset its working on so `var filterMembers(membershipData);`  then I would want to make different filtered implementations `var femaleMembers = filterMembers(isFemaleFilter);` which would be an `array.filter()` function.

How would one achieve this?

---

edit:

I wasn't very clear in my qeustion, apologies. I would like for the array and the filter to be variable. I want to compose seperate functions from the partial implementations.

so I might create a partial implementation that works on the membership array or another that works on census data or something. Then I would like to compose functions from those partial implementations passing different filter functions to the partial implentations that work on the different data sets.

I'm afraid I don't know how to write working code that demonstrates my question.

Comment: What's the content of `arr`? Running code and a small explanation is better than a long paragraph

Comment: `const filterMembers = pred => members => members.filter(pred)` in which `pred` is a function of `any -> boolean`?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please clearly provide the problem you try to solve (in code) so input data, output data. Also, show us what you've tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a partial implementation of the filter function:

```
const filter = fn => arr =>
    arr.filter(fn)
```

```js
const members = [
  {name: 'eminem', sex: 'male'},
  {name: 'rihanna', sex: 'female'}
]

const filter = fn => arr =>
  arr.filter(fn)
  
const isFemale = x =>
  x.sex === 'female'
  
const filterFemaleMembers = filter(isFemale)

console.log(filterFemaleMembers(members))
```

It is better to first pass the `fn` and than the `arr` to `filter` because it has a benefit when you compose functions:

```js
const members = [
  {name: 'Eminem', sex: 'male'},
  {name: 'Rihanna', sex: 'female', age: 28},
  {name: 'Lana Del Rey', sex: 'female', age: 31}
]

const filter = fn => arr =>
  arr.filter(fn)
  
const compose = f => g => x =>
  f(g(x))
  
const isFemale = x =>
  x.sex === 'female'

const isOlder30 = x =>
  x.age > 30

const isFemaleAndOlder30 = compose
  (filter (isFemale))
  (filter (isOlder30))


console.log(
  isFemaleAndOlder30 (members)
)
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting. But the compose function isn't curried, is there no way to achieve the behaviour with fully curried functions?

Comment: shure. I changed it to a curried version.

Comment: I added some more infromation to my question. 
I would like to create partial implementations that work on different datasets and then construct different functions that fitler their respective datasets by passing a filter function as one of the function parameters

Comment: thanks for the update to your sample. Is there a way I can edit the snippet to see how it works a bit clearer or should I copy it into an external tool?

Comment: I've been checking over the code and its rpetty cool, thanks. Took a minute to understand though, not used to this : )

Comment: Am I right in saying that in functional programming data should always come last?

Comment: I don't know if this is rule.. but you will get the right order of your params when you want to _compose_ your functions ;)

Comment: Well thanks for your help, your example helped me grok the concept at last. I actually got a book on functional javascript as part of the pakt functional programming humble bundle that is going on at the moment so I'll probably have a read through that now. Cheers : )